# Is there a C++ function that helps to evaluate parentheses?

Tags: c++, string, parentheses

For example, if the input is "(A + (BC)) (giggity (this text) isn't in the expression)", it would return (0, 9), because the first parenthesis is on 0 and the second is on 9?

If not, please tell me how to construct a function that takes a string as its arguments so I can do it myself.

Comment: What does (0, 9) have anything to do with that input? I'm confused about what you're asking for.

Comment: @Falmarri it gives you the position of the parantheses.

Comment: Yeah, the first parenthesis and its matching parenthesis.

Comment: There, that should make it clearer what 0 and 9 are.

Comment: Right.  The first `(` is at index 0 and the matching `)` is at index 9.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. It's the position in the string of un-nested open parenthesis? This seems like a pretty specific requirement. If you wanted to extract the subexpressions, there's probably a library for that.

Comment: Also, can your expressions contain string literals?  Dealing with `(S + ")")` would make things more complicated.

Comment: That's not really necessary. It's for a lambda calculus to combinatory logic converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function built into the standard library that does that, but it's really easy to write:

```
pair<int,int> findparens( const char* input )
{
    int depth = 0;
    int first;
    for( const char* c = input; *c; ++c ) {
        if (*c == '(' && !depth++) first = c - input;
        else if (*c == ')' && !--depth) return make_pair(first, c - input);
    }
    throw depth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This should suffice. I'm using it to make a converter from lambda calculus to combinatory logic.

Answer (score 4):

Matching parentheses are usually found using stack: traverse string left ro right, when you find opening one, you push current position to the stack, when you find closing one - you pop value from the stack. Popped value will be the position of matching opening parenthesis.

Comment: That's pretty helpful, but I'm looking for a function I can just plug a string into.

Comment: If you only have one type of bracket, you don't need a stack, just a single integer variable containing the nesting level.

Comment: +1 for stacks. Couldn't agree more. @dan04 such a function is trivial to write, but won't help. Not if you are interested in parsing the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a [lexer](http://www.gnu.org/software/flex/) and [parser generator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to tell you how to construct such a function because I think what you want to do is evaluate those, and hence create a parser, and just knowing the position is wrong.

For example, consider:

```
(a+b(c+d))(((d)(e+f)))
```

How does knowing the position help you parse that expression?

As n0rd has just posted, you want a stack machine to do this. Consider the FILO (First in, Last Out) model to the order of evaluation of the parentheses... inside out.